# Customizing Bootstrapper UI similar to the customized wix UI

Tags: wix, installation, bootstrapper, wix3.6, wix3.7

I have created a setup using wix,where i have created customized UI in wix related to my project.but now i need to add prerequisite install .For prerequisite  installs i used bootstrapper (seems its only way to add prerequisite in wix ). But now my problem is am not getting my customized UI which i developed in WIx using `<UIRef Id="MyWixUI_InstallDir" />`  , instead am getting standard bootstrapper UI's. Is it possible to use the same wix UI in bootstrapper   ?? and is bootstrapper the only way to add  prerequisite  using wix ..?

Thanks,
Arshad

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices:

1. You could customize the bootstrapper UI and pass properties to the MSI or,
2. to show both the bootstrapper and the MSI UI, set MsiPackage/@[DisplayInternalUI](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/msipackage.html)="yes".

The WiX Bootstrapper is a well-thoughtout bootstrapper, downloader, chainer, reboot handler, and package manager for Windows. It is the best practice when using WiX for prerequisites. (But, there are other bootstrappers out there.) Visual Studio, WiX itself, and many other fine products so use it.

Comment: I would go with the second choice,that is what i expected :) :) @Tom Blodget

Comment: Is there any way to make bootstrapper auto download prerequisite from web? @tom

Comment: Yes, look at the DownloadUrl attribute of the ExePackage or MsiPackage. See the WiX source code for examples of the predefined packages.